# Is it possible to send a key code to an application that is not in front?

Tags: javascript, macos, applescript, automator

I'm writing a simple Automator script in Javascript.

I want to send a key-code(or key-storke) to an OS X application that is not in front.

Basically, I want to run this code and do my things while the script opens a certain application, write text, and hit enter - all of this without bothering my other work.

I want something like this:

`Application("System Events").processes['someApp'].windows[0].textFields[0].keyCode(76);`

In Script Dictionary, there is `keyCode` method under `Processes Suite`.
The above code, however, throws an error that follows:

`execution error: Error on line 16: Error: Named parameters must be passed as an object. (-2700)`

I understand that the following code works fine, but it require the application to be running in front:

`// KeyCode 76 => "Enter"
Application("System Events").keyCode(76);`

**UPDATE**: I'm trying to search something on iTunes(Apple Music). Is this possible without bringing iTunes app upfront?

Comment: The System Events `key code` _command_ only act upon what has focus.

Comment: From my experience with "enter", I don't think that is the case. KeyCode method act the same as Keystroke method with "enter" key code. An "enter" is sent to the front application at the time of calling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to write text in application that is not in front with the help of the **GUI Scripting** (**accessibility**), but :

- You need to know what UI elements are in the window of your specific
  application, and to know the attributes and properties of the
  specific element.
- You need to add your script in  the `System Preferences --> Security
  & Privacy --> Accessibility`.

---

Here's a sample script (tested on **macOS Sierra**) to write some text at the position of the cursor in the front document of the "**TextEdit**" application.

```
Application("System Events").processes['TextEdit'].windows[0].scrollAreas[0].textAreas[0].attributes["AXSelectedText"].value = "some text" + "\r" // r is the return KEY
```

---

**Update**

To send some key code to a background application, you can use the `CGEventPostToPid()` method of the **Carbon** framework.

Here's the script to search some text in iTunes (Works on my computer, **macOS Sierra** and **iTunes Version 10.6.2**).

```
ObjC.import('Carbon')
iPid = Application("System Events").processes['iTunes'].unixId()
searchField = Application("System Events").processes['iTunes'].windows[0].textFields[0]
searchField.buttons[0].actions['AXPress'].perform()
delay(0.1) // increase it, if no search 
searchField.focused = true
delay(0.3) // increase it, if no search 
searchField.value = "world" // the searching text
searchField.actions["AXConfirm"].perform()
delay(0.1) // increase it, if no search 

// ** carbon methods to send the enter key to a background application ***
enterDown = $.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent($(), 76, true);
enterUp = $.CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent($(), 76, false);
$.CGEventPostToPid(iPid, enterDown);
delay(0.1)
$.CGEventPostToPid(iPid, enterUp);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I'm talking about actual "Enter" capability here. My script writes the text to that UIElement correctly, but it requires the application to be upfront with "enter" key code. I'm trying to hit "enter" without activating the application to the front.

Comment: It's impossible to help without knowing the name of your application, and to know what happens when you press the "Enter" key. But, there are some action (**if available**) which simulate the enter key on some ui elements, **AppleScript** example: `perform action "AXConfirm" of someSpecificElement...`

Comment: Ahh - sorry about the lack of information. I'm trying to search something on iTunes(Apple Music). I have tried the perform "confirm" action with no success - nothing happens. Is this possible without bringing iTunes app upfront?